# Regex for time ranges starting too far

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find time ranges of the form

```
12:30 Test
12:30-12:50 Test
```

with the simple regex `((\d+):(\d+)-?)+ (.*)`. It works fine for the first example, but for the second example, the match only begins at `12:50`, and doesn't catch the first time range.

Do you see why ?

Here is a [Regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/bkkYbe/1) and a minimal example in Python:

```
   import re
   print(re.search("^((\d+)(?::|h)(\d+)-?)+ (\w.*)", "12:30-12:50 Test").groups())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access repeated captures with Python `re`, you need to explicitly unwrap the quantified group and make the second part optional:

```
(\d+):(\d+)(?:-(\d+):(\d+))? (.*)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6v9P8z/1)

[Python demo](http://ideone.com/zznwv2):

```
import re
rx = r"(\d+):(\d+)(?:-(\d+):(\d+))? (.*)"
strs = ["12:30 Test", "12:30-12:50 Test"]
for str in strs:
    m = re.search(rx, str)
    if m:
        print(m.groups())
```

Output:

```
('12', '30', None, None, 'Test')
('12', '30', '12', '50', 'Test')
```

With [PyPi `regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/2016.10.22), you can access all the `captures`, see an example with your regex:

```
>>> import regex
>>> strs = ["12:30 Test", "12:30-12:50 Test"]
>>> for str in strs:
    m = regex.search(r'((\d+):(\d+)-?)+ (.*)', str)
    if m:
        print(m.captures(1))
        print(m.captures(2))
        print(m.captures(3))


['12:30']
['12']
['30']
['12:30-', '12:50']
['12', '12']
['30', '50']
>>>
```